# Android: View Image in normal size from gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am using gridview for images from specific folder. i want to create code in onitemclick event. that when i click on image it is showed in full size. I have tried some codes from stackoverflow but that weren't working in my case. My code for gridview is

```
public class PrivateGallery extends Activity {
private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
File[] listFile;
private Context mcontext;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    getFromSdcard();
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagegrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File afile = new File(f.get(position));
            if (afile.delete()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file not deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    ;

    imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            File afile = new File(f.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), f.get(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    });

}

public void getFromSdcard() {
    File file = new File(
            "/data/data/com.mati.testprivatefolder/cache/MyPrivateFolder2//");

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
            } else {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }

        }
    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mcontext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return f.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        return convertView;
    }

}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;

}

}
```

Please help me to write code for it. Thanks.